# PostgreSQL remote access error

Tags: macos, postgresql

I'm a novice in PostgreSQL.
Now I'm trying to access a remote DB in PostgreSQL(9.3.3) with `psql` command like:

```
:~ tomohitoy$ psql -U root -h [my remote host's ip address]
```

However this returns an error message like:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"
```

in MacOSX 10.9.2, PostgreSQL was installed by homebrew, running PostgreSQL.

in postgresql.conf(local)

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

in pg_hba.conf(local)

```
host  all  all  [my remote host's ip address]  trust
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the password prompt on the command line, so you would need to have it specified in the **PGPASSWORD** environment variable for **root** user. You could alternately use the `-W` option to have psql prompt you to type in the password.

This assumes you have defined a **root** user in postgres and set its password.

There is also the `.pgpass` file: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-pgpass.html

**Edit factoring in OP's comment:**

If you don't have a user named **root** on your Postgres server, that would be the proximal issue. The user and password you use to connect to `Postgres` must exist in the `Postgres` instance to which you're connecting.

There should be at least one user in there you created during install (quite likely called **postgres**, although it could be something else).

You can also create new users (roles) in `Postgres`:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-createuser.html

**Edit 2 factoring in OP's additional comments**

In the case you outline below -- connecting to a colleague's remote `Postgres` server -- then your local `Postgres` server doesn't matter at all for this, since you're not (with that command) trying to connect to it.

You need to use a `user` and a `password` that are defined on the **remote Postgres server** (not a *nix account) to which you are trying to connect. Your colleagues will need to provide you with credentials you can use to connect. They should either have an user created specifically for you, or a shared user whose credentials you can use.

A special config should not be needed simply to connect to a server in the way you are stating. Simply specify the user on the cmdline and the password via one of the methods above.

The main config file that really matters for `psql` (that is, the **client** side of `Postgres` as opposed to the **server**) is `.psqlrc`, in which you can define an assortment of settings and customizations for psql sessions.

**Note:**

For some operations, a special config of sorts would be required. For example, some `Postgres` operations require the superuser role, and so you would need to login with a special `superuser` user in that case, but for basic things, as long as the user you login as has access to the database to which you're trying to connect, that should be fine.

**Also:**

The `psql` command above needs a `database target` at the end. It could be the default `template1` database if, say, you want to create a new database and work with that, after the creation of which you can then switch the connection to that new database.

Comment: Thank you, Ken. I've tried that with `-W` option, and typed the password of remote host. 
However, that returns the same error like 

`:~ tomohitoy$ psql -U root -h [my remote host's ip address] -W`  
`Password for user root:`  
`psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"`  
I don't have any root user in my local PostgreSQL server. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Also, you mention **local PostgreSQL server** and **remote host**. Are those different things? The host you specify to psql should be the host of the Postgres server to which you want to connect, whether it's local or remote, and the user must exist on that instance.

Comment: Dear Ken. Yes, those are different things. I would like to connect to remote SQL server from my local laptop. The remote server is managed by my colleagues.

Comment: I would like to know whether a special configuration in my local laptop is necessary or not, when I want to connect a remote PostgreSQL server.

Comment: OK. Will add more details to my answer above.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ken :) I understand that it's not necessary for me to make some special configurations in my laptop. I will ask my colleague to check configurations in his database.